# How create fringes without spaces in emacs

Tags: emacs, fringe

How to remove bottom vertical space between fringes ?

[fringes-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSjvX.png)

I have the following code

```
(defun test--fringe() 
  (interactive) 
  (save-excursion (let ((ov (make-overlay (point) 
                                          (+ 1 (point))))) 
                    (overlay-put ov 'before-string (propertize "x" 'display '(left-fringe
                                                                              filled-rectangle
                                                                              error)))) 
                  (forward-line)
                  (let ((ov (make-overlay (point) 
                                          (+ 1 (point))))) 
                    (overlay-put ov 'before-string (propertize "x" 'display '(left-fringe
                                                                              filled-rectangle
                                                                              error))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you see that if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? I don't. If you don't, then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

---

Perhaps you or some code you use has customized option `line-spacing`? `C-h v` says:

> **`line-spacing`** is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>
> Its value is `nil`
>
> Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.
>
> Documentation:
>
> Additional space to put between lines when displaying a buffer.
>
> The space is measured in pixels, and put below lines on graphic displays,
> see `display-graphic-p`.
>
> If value is a floating point number, it specifies the spacing relative
> to the default frame line height.  A value of `nil` means add no extra space.
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
> version 22.1 of Emacs.

Comment: I checked `line-spacing` it's `nil`

Comment: Do you see the problem with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Yes, there is small offset between fringes.
sorry, maybe I described my question not very well
I would try to do something like this
[diff-hl](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dgutov/diff-hl/master/screenshot.png) purle changes in the editor

Comment: If you see the problem even with `emacs -Q` (no init file) then consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. It may be platform-dependent. I don't see what you apparently see, with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: BTW - it looks like your screenshot is showing `vi` instead of Emacs - e.g., all those `~` lines at the end. Is that really what you see with `emacs -Q`?